# TableLayout inside ListView

Tags: android, listview, tablelayout

There is a page in my android application which has a slide out menu and some data that needs to be displayed in the main screen. The slide out menu has the required menu options.

the main page is in ListView format. I want a TableLayout format layout inside this ListView.
The problem is when i change the layout to TableLayout, it messes up with my java activity file.

I want to display data extracted from an external source on the main screen of this page in table format.

The XML and Java Activity files are enclosed.

Thanks in advance.

XML Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="@drawable/galaxy">

<!-- Menu Panel -->
<RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/menuPanel"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="right"
       android:background="@drawable/grey"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/menu_title_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" 
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"             
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/grey"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="MAIN  MENU">     
        </TextView>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/menu_item_divider_1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0.5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_title_1"
            android:background="#000000"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/readall"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"             
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_below="@+id/menu_item_divider_1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="All Parameters"/>     


          <Button
            android:id="@+id/param1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"             
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_below="@+id/readall"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Parameter 1"/>    

             <Button
            android:id="@+id/param2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"             
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_below="@+id/param1"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Parameter 2"/>    

             <Button
            android:id="@+id/param3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"             
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_below="@+id/param2"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Parameter 3"/>    

             <Button
            android:id="@+id/dtc"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"             
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_below="@+id/param3"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="D.T.C."/>    


             <Button
            android:id="@+id/logout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"             
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_below="@+id/dtc"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Log Out"/>    

        </RelativeLayout>

   <!-- Sliding Panel -->     
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/slidingPanel"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/grey" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/black" >

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/header_vertical_divider_1"
                    android:layout_width="2dp"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menuViewButton"
                    android:background="@drawable/grey" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/menuViewButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:contentDescription="Main Menu"
                        android:textColor="#000000"
                        android:src="@drawable/icon"
                        android:visibility="visible" />


                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/header_vertical_divider_1"
                        android:text="ECU Description"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                 android:id="@+id/dividerHeaderBottom"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="1dp"
                 android:background="#414141" ></View>
             <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:divider="#000000"
                android:dividerHeight="0.5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/galaxy"         >

            </ListView>


    </LinearLayout>

             <LinearLayout
                 android:id="@+id/footer"
                 style="@android:style/ButtonBar"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="50dp"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                 android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
                 android:background="@drawable/black"
                 android:orientation="horizontal" >

           <EditText
                android:id="@+id/DefUid"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_weight="0.50"
                android:digits="0123456789."
                android:hint="IP Address"
                android:maxLength="15"
                android:maxWidth="350dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing" >


            </EditText>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/DefUid"
                android:layout_width="0px"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_weight="0.20"
                android:maxWidth="80dip"
                android:hint="Port"
                android:digits="0123456789"
                android:maxLength="4"
                android:singleLine="true" >

            </EditText>


                     <Button
                        android:id="@+id/conn"
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.15"
                        android:text="C"/>



                   <Button
                        android:id="@+id/disc"
                        android:layout_width="0px"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.15"
                        android:text="D"/>

                </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Java Activity File

```
public class LayerStack extends Activity 
{

//Declare
private LinearLayout slidingPanel;
private boolean isExpanded;
private DisplayMetrics metrics; 
private ListView listView;
private RelativeLayout headerPanel;
private RelativeLayout menuPanel;
private int panelWidth;
private ImageView menuViewButton;
private static final int HIDE_TOOLBARS = 0;
private static final int SHOW_TOOLBARS = 1;
private static final int TOGGLE_TOOLBARS = 2;
Handler handler;
LinearLayout toolbarTop, toolbarBottom;


FrameLayout.LayoutParams menuPanelParameters;
FrameLayout.LayoutParams slidingPanelParameters;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams headerPanelParameters ;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams listViewParameters;


//@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{   
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.page7);
    //ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menuPanel);
    //myImage.setAlpha(100);
    // Get references to the elements in the layout

    //Initialize
    metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    panelWidth = (int) ((metrics.widthPixels)*0.50);

    headerPanel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.header);
    headerPanelParameters = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) headerPanel.getLayoutParams();
    headerPanelParameters.width = metrics.widthPixels;
    headerPanel.setLayoutParams(headerPanelParameters);

    menuPanel = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.menuPanel);
    menuPanelParameters = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) menuPanel.getLayoutParams();
    menuPanelParameters.width = panelWidth;
    menuPanel.setLayoutParams(menuPanelParameters);

    slidingPanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.slidingPanel);
    slidingPanelParameters = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) slidingPanel.getLayoutParams();
    slidingPanelParameters.width = metrics.widthPixels;
    slidingPanel.setLayoutParams(slidingPanelParameters);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listViewParameters = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) listView.getLayoutParams();
    listViewParameters.width = metrics.widthPixels;
    listView.setLayoutParams(listViewParameters);


    //Slide the Panel   
    menuViewButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.menuViewButton);
    menuViewButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!isExpanded)
            {
                isExpanded = true;                                              

                //Expand
                new ExpandAnimation(slidingPanel, panelWidth,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.50f, 0, 0.0f, 0, 0.0f);   


                Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.readall);
                b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        Intent i = new Intent(LayerStack.this,AppActivity8.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();

                    }
                });
               Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
                b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) 
                    {
                        new AlertDialog.Builder(LayerStack.this)
                        .setTitle("Log Out Confirmation")
                        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to log out?")
                        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0,int arg1)
                            {
                                Intent i = new Intent(LayerStack.this,AppActivity4.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();

                            }

                        }).create().show();

                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                isExpanded = false;
                //Collapse
                new CollapseAnimation(slidingPanel,panelWidth,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.50f,
                TranslateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f, 0, 0.0f, 0, 0.0f);


            }

        }
    });

}       
}
```

Comment: This site isn't for writing you code. Its for solving problems AFTER you try.
#1 Rule What have you tried

Comment: yes i knw that. i tried to add the TableLayout but it did not work. sadly i dnt have the modified one. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Used MultiColumn ListView Instead.